# tf.reshape versus (tf.expand_dims + tf.squeeze... etc)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Are there any performance improvements to be had from using `tf.expand_dims()` or `tf.squeeze()`... etc instead of `tf.reshape()`?

It feels like for readability `tf.reshape()` is often the best choice because you can perform any amount/combination of the reshaping steps in one line and you're absolutely sure what the final shape will be.

However, I've read that `tf.reshape()` makes copies of the data internally.  Does `tf.expand_dims()` or `tf.squeeze()` not do this?  Are there performance improvements or other reasons to use the competitors to `tf.reshape()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `TF1.x`, in particular in `TF1.12.0`, all of the methods have the same performance on *CPU*:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('cpu:0'):
    tensor = tf.random.normal(shape=(1, 3, 2))

    newaxis = tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
    expanded_dims = tf.expand_dims(tensor, 0)
    reshaped = tf.reshape(tensor, (1, ) + tuple(tensor.get_shape().as_list()))

    squeezed = tf.squeeze(tensor)
    reshaped2 = tf.reshape(tensor, (3, 2))

sess = tf.Session()
%timeit -n 10000 sess.run(newaxis) # 84.3 µs ± 767 ns per loop 
%timeit -n 10000 sess.run(expanded_dims) # 83.3 µs ± 837 ns per loop
%timeit -n 10000 sess.run(reshaped) # 83.5 µs ± 946 ns per loop

%timeit -n 10000 sess.run(squeezed) # 81.9 µs ± 852 ns per loop
%timeit -n 10000 sess.run(reshaped2) # 83.9 µs ± 852 ns per loop
```

On *GPU*, `tf.newaxis` and `tf.squeeze()` are the fastest ones:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('gpu:0'):
    tensor = tf.random.normal(shape=(1, 3, 2))

    newaxis = tensor[tf.newaxis, ...] # <-- Fastest to add new axis
    expanded_dims = tf.expand_dims(tensor, 0)
    reshaped = tf.reshape(tensor, (1, ) + tuple(tensor.get_shape().as_list()))

    squeezed = tf.squeeze(tensor) # <-- Fastest to remove unit-sized dims
    reshaped2 = tf.reshape(tensor, (3, 2))

sess = tf.Session()
%timeit -n 10000 sess.run(newaxis) # 133 µs ± 1.58 µs per loop
%timeit -n 10000 sess.run(expanded_dims) # 140 µs ± 1.4 µs per loop
%timeit -n 10000 sess.run(reshaped) #153 µs ± 1.22 µs per loop

%timeit -n 10000 sess.run(squeezed) # 134 µs ± 1.86 µs per loop
%timeit -n 10000 sess.run(reshaped2) # 153 µs ± 1.19 µs per loop
```

In `TF2.0` `tf.expand_dims()` to add dimension and `tf.squeeze()` are the fastest (*CPU*):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.random.normal(shape=(1, 3, 2))

%timeit -n 10000 tf.expand_dims(tensor, 0) # 7.07 µs ± 162 ns per loop
%timeit -n 10000 tf.reshape(tensor, (1, ) + tuple(tensor.shape.as_list())) # 21.3 µs ± 326 ns per loop
%timeit -n 10000 tensor[tf.newaxis, ...] # 42.9 µs ± 565 ns per loop

%timeit -n 10000 tf.squeeze(tensor) # 9.85 µs ± 166 ns per loop
%timeit -n 10000 tf.reshape(tensor, shape=(3, 2)) # 18.2 µs ± 386 ns per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this!  I imagined the simpler operation would be ever so slightly faster intuitively, but it's especially good to know that TF2.0 has differing results.

Comment: I'm not sure that the benchmarks provided here are relevant, as the operations are very small; I expect the overhead of sess.run (in TF 1) and eager execution (in TF 2) are dominant here.